# How Read different data type in text file using python & assign them to variables using python

Tags: python, file-handling

1. Rohan M 90
2. Kumarasinghe M 67

I want to read them individually and need to assign the flowing variable.
Y G N

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())

    arr = []

    for _ in range(n):
        arr.append(list(map(str, input().rstrip().split())))

N=arr[0]
G=arr[1]
Y=int(arr[2])
```

This Code doesn't work

Comment: How do you know this doesn't work?

Comment: Q1. Are you taking 1 input at a tine? Q2.Y, G, N - are they lists also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for _ in range(n):
    arr = [x for x in input().split()]

N=arr[0]
G=arr[1]
Y=int(arr[2])
```

This should work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed like this :

```
N,G,Y = input().strip().split(' ')
```